# Converting pairwise distances into a distance matrix in R

Tags: r, excel

I have pairwise distances that I need to display/convert into a distance matrix. R should have a function for this but I am not sure which one or how to use the same. My data looks like below

```
A1  A1  0.90
A1  B1  0.85
A1  C1  0.45
A1  D1  0.96
B1  B1  0.90
B1  C1  0.85
B1  D1  0.56
C1  C1  0.55
C1  D1  0.45
D1  D1  0.90
```

I want to convert/display it as below

```
      A1      B1      C1      D1
A1    0.90    0.85    0.45    0.96
B1            0.90    0.85    0.56
C1                    0.55    0.45
D1                            0.90
```

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps manipulate the output of `?xtabs`?. `xtabs(DF[, 3] ~ DF[, 1] + DF[, 2])`

Comment: @alexis_laz - that should be an answer. The examples in `?as.table` note: `xtabs() <-> as.data.frame.table()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `reshape`:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("
A1  A1  0.90
A1  B1  0.85
A1  C1  0.45
A1  D1  0.96
B1  B1  0.90
B1  C1  0.85
B1  D1  0.56
C1  C1  0.55
C1  D1  0.45
D1  D1  0.90"))

dfr <- reshape(df, direction="wide", idvar="V2", timevar="V1")
dfr
#   V2 V3.A1 V3.B1 V3.C1 V3.D1
# 1 A1  0.90    NA    NA    NA
# 2 B1  0.85  0.90    NA    NA
# 3 C1  0.45  0.85  0.55    NA
# 4 D1  0.96  0.56  0.45   0.9

d <- as.dist(dfr[, -1])
d
#      1    2    3
# 2 0.85          
# 3 0.45 0.85     
# 4 0.96 0.56 0.45

# reset labels
attr(d, "Labels") <- dfr[, 1]
d
#      A1   B1   C1
# B1 0.85          
# C1 0.45 0.85     
# D1 0.96 0.56 0.45
```

---

The solution mentioned by @alexis_laz seems to be more elegant:

```
as.dist(xtabs(df[, 3] ~ df[, 2] + df[, 1]))
#      A1   B1   C1
# B1 0.85          
# C1 0.45 0.85     
# D1 0.96 0.56 0.45
```

Comment: But How do I get the labels back instead of 1,2,3?

Comment: Please see my edit. BTW I really like the solution of @alexis_laz.

Comment: Yes! the xtabs solution works. But I also wanted the A1,B1,C1 and D1 values to themselves. That is A1-A1, B1-B1 and so on. How do I get those in the table?

Comment: @user45270: I am not quite sure but I think the `dist` class doesn't save the diagonal values (because they are mostly 1 or 0). BTW why are your diagonal values are different from 0/1 and different between A1-A1 and e.g. C1-C1?

Comment: Hey, The values are DNA sequence similarities between species and within the same species. Something curious going on in this genus, or there could have been a technical error somewhere in the sequencing.